# magento 2 : Get country from IP address

Tags: magento-2.1, country-regions, countries, geoip, ip-address

How to get the name of the country from the ip address in magento 2. I think it will require me to use geoip, but I don't know how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code:

```
    protected $logger;

    protected $objectManager;

    protected $_curl;

    public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, 
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_curl = $curl;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function getCountryName() {
        $visitorIp = $this->getVisitorIp();
        $url = "freegeoip.net/json/".$visitorIp;
        $this->_curl->get($url);
        $response = json_decode($this->_curl->getBody(), true);
        $countryName = $response['country_name'];
        $stateName = $response['region_name'];
       return $stateName;        
    }

    function getVisitorIp() {       
        $remoteAddress = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
        return $remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    }
```

Comment: where i need to add this code

Comment: need to add this code in observer @Prashant Valanda

Comment: @Nadh you can add it in block or where you want

Comment: what is  $response['country_name'];

Comment: @ Prashant Valanda  iam not getting

Comment: This is country name according to ip address.

Comment: how to call country name in template file

Comment: add above code in block file call it  `echo $block->getCountryName();` in template file

Comment: @nadh update code with state name please check it.

Comment: how to get region code

Comment: using `$response['region_code']` code you will get region code

Comment: i already tried this but its not working

Comment: call this url `http://freegeoip.net/json/your-ip-address` check response there is region code as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48580/discussion-between-nadh-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: Adding a request to another page will slow down a lot your clients website.

Comment: any limit applicable on this freegeoip.net site ?

Comment: 10.000 requests / mo on free account

Comment: where did you add this code ...

Comment: You can use it in block, helper, controller anywhere as per your requirement

Comment: freegeoip.net service seems to be dead, guys