# Redirect to different store view according to IP Magento 2.1.9

Tags: redirect, magento-2.1.9

I have a 2 website in 1 installation with 2 store views each. The store views are **GBP** and **USA** and the difference is just the price.

I have manage to redirect each website properly using **.htaccess**. The problem is that I want to redirect now each customer to proper store view according to their IP.

**I know how to get the proper store view by IP so lets ignore that part.**

I am looking at `\Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context` where magento is doing something with a plugin. It looks promising but I still can't work out how to do it.

Any ideas?

PS: As I already explained above I know how to get the store view by IP. The part I m asking is on how to redirect the customer to the proper store view.

PS2: For the third time I ll point this:
**I know how to get the proper store view by IP so lets ignore that part.**

People please read the question before you say this is a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps [`mod_geoip`](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/) and set the store id in htaccess using [`STORE_RUN_CODE`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html). I don't know enough about either to write a full answer

Comment: How is this question a duplication of what you say @PY Yick ? I clearly state that I know how to get the IP and I m asking for how to do the redirection and on what step.

Comment: OK I missed your key sentence so it's not duplicate. BTW you can try this one for store redirection: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195235/different-category-urls-for-store-views-redirect-to-proper-one#comment270229_195235

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento 2 : Track country with ip address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145804/magento-2-track-country-with-ip-address)