# How to get Geo IP of customer in magento2?

Tags: magento2, geoip

I want to get the customer geo IP in magento2. I used some third party calls but If I enable proxy means that thing is not working. How can I get the original customer IP in magento2 anybody has idea means please tell me.

I referred this one but in proxy, it's not working,
[magento 2 : Track country with ip address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145804/magento-2-track-country-with-ip-address)

Comment: Is your question asking how to get the real/original IP of someone using a proxy?

Comment: I need to get customer location to give offers to those customers likewise am asking @John

Comment: Ah, so a discount/offers based on customers from a particular country. I'd suggest updating your question to make this clearer as I didnt entirely understand what you wanted at first

Answer (score 0):

I have used this extension to get country code of customer.
[RefernceLink](https://marketplace.magento.com/yogeshkhasturi-geoipredirection.html)

Comment: This extension was not available. Please share if any other working extension.